# DynamoDB Terraform: ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create an item in DynamoDB using terraform and facing this error:

```
reading DynamoDB Table Item (snflk_execution_process_details|execution_key||control-tower_execution|):
ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema status code: 400, request id: ... with aws_dynamodb_table_item.control-tower_execution_STG_TJOB, on DynamoDB_Items.tf line 101, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "control-tower_execution_STG_TJOB": 101: resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "control-tower_execution_STG_TJOB"
```

This is the terraform resource I'm using. C

```hcl
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "control-tower_execution_STG_TJOB" {
  table_name = "snflk_execution_process_details"
  hash_key   = "execution_key"
  range_key  = "process_key"
  item = <<ITEM
{
  "execution_key": {
    "S": "control-tower_execution"
  },
  "process_key": {
    "S": "STG_TJOB"
  },
  "application": {
    "S": "control_tower"
  },
  "batch": {
    "N": "1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "S": "control-tower/sf-trf/STG_TJOB.sql"
  },
  "sql_dict": {
    "S": "None"
  },
  "target_table_name": {
    "S": "STG_TJOB"
  }
}
ITEM
}
```

This is the DynamoDB Table

```hcl
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "snflk_execution_process_details" {
  name         = "snflk_execution_process_details"
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key     = "execution_key"
  range_key    = "process_key"

  attribute {
    name = "execution_key"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "process_key"
    type = "S"
  }


  point_in_time_recovery {
    enabled = false
  }
}
```

Comment: @Maurice 
```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "snflk_execution_process_details" {
  name         = "snflk_execution_process_details"
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key     = "execution_key"
  range_key    = "process_key"

  attribute {
    name = "execution_key"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "process_key"
    type = "S"
  }


  point_in_time_recovery {
    enabled = false
  }
}
```

Comment: @Maurice ihave uploaded that part of code too.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem - **your code is correct**, the table and the item are created. You should consider referencing the table name for the item instead of hard-coding it so terraform understands there is a dependency between the two resources.

Comment: I can confirm @Maurice finding. Just run your code, and it works perfectly fine for me as well.